# I can't render images from an API in my fronted application

Tags: node.js, reactjs, api, express

I'm building an appplication using react at the front and express at the back in order to avoid cors issues. From the back I get the Json of my API from "Zoho Creator". Here an example.
[image] As you can see I get a Json object, but in the image value, the URL appear without https://zoho.creator.eu... and when I try to request them from my frontend I can't render them. and if I add https://... at the beginning manually I get an error 401. I also tried to add the https route from the backend but is the same thing.
Here my backend using express
PD: I'm a rookie I know, please don't judge me.

```js
const express = require("express")
const app = express()
const fetch = require("node-fetch")
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const cors = require("cors")
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 4000;
app.use(bodyParser.json());
const urlPost = ("https://accounts.zoho.eu/oauth/v2/token?refresh_token=1000.3dbdad6937dc0800c4dcc662cd14d173.86efb18e337989bebb3ff4c05582c94c&client_id=1000.NQL17JHK3Y62Y178TO0E3FQC6MBQJV&client_secret=5d04ad135862e7313377484af55efa1f41c1f49a39&grant_type=refresh_token")
const urlGet = "https://creator.zoho.eu/api/v2/hostienda1/Product-Catalog/report/Product_Details";
app.use(cors())
app.get
const peticion = fetch(urlPost,{
  method: 'POST',
  redirect: 'follow'
});
peticion
.then((ans)=>{return ans.json()})
.then((resp)=>{
  const reslt = resp.access_token;
  return app.get("*", async (req,res)=>{
    const response = await fetch(urlGet,{
    method: "GET",
    headers:{
        'Authorization':`Zoho-oauthtoken ${reslt}`,
      }})
      const result = await response.json()
      const test = result.data
      test.map(function(product){
            if (true){
              product.Product_Images[0] = "https://creator.zoho.eu" + product.Product_Images[0].display_value
            return product.Product_Images[0]
            }
          })

      res.json(test)
      
    })
  })
app.listen(PORT, () => {console.log(`Listening on port ${PORT}`)})`
```

I hope to render my images from my frontend app.

Comment: In editing your question I noticed spaces in the URLs. `token?   refresh_token` and `/Product- Catalog`  are they intentional / actually there or was this an accidental artifact of posting the question?

Comment: Yes, I think it was modified by stackoverflow I guess because I copied and pasted my code, but my code doesn't have spaces at the URL.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the download link for the image also requires authentication, in other words, the download requires a request like

```
GET https://creator.zoho.eu/api/v2/hostienda1/Product-Catalog/report/Product_Details/...jpg
Authorization: Zoho-oauthtoken ...
```

Such a request cannot be made your frontend, because it does not know the `Zoho-oauthtoken`.

This means that you must make this request in your backend. Rewrite your middleware so that it retrieves the download link for *one* image only (currently you return `test`, which contains *many* images). Then use the following code to access the image at that download link and return it to the frontend:

```js
var img = await fetch("https://creator.zoho.eu/api/v2/...", // the download link
  {headers: {authorization: `Zoho-oauthtoken ${reslt}`}}
);
res.set("content-type", img.headers.get("content-type"));
stream.Readable.fromWeb(img.body).pipe(res);
```